# Reading file line by line but start from some point

Tags: python-3.x, file

I have to read a file line by line but start printing it's contest after a match occur. Let's assume the match should be XXX

So, if we have a file with the following

```
wdwdw
dwdww
XXX
DWDM
111
```

it should display DWDM and 111

I tryed it the following way.

```
file open('buffer.txt', 'r')
for line in file:
    if re.search('XXX'. line):
          print(line)
```

But it prints only one line. How to force it to print the rest?

Answer (score 1):

It only print the matching line, which is normal. Try something like that:

```
with open('buffer.txt', 'r') as f:
    matched = False 
    for line in f:
        if matched:
            print(line)
        if re.search('XXX', line):
            matched = True
```

> [Why to prefer the use of `with` to open a file](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python)

Comment: Note this will print the `XXX` line which was not desired in the OP's output. It also uses `re.search` which as an unneeded import for a trivial `in` search. That being said we both had the same idea :P

Comment: You're right about the order of operations, fixed it

Comment: However, the use of `re`, even if it seems trivial in the example, could be needed for the real use case, for example if the file is a log file with dates...

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't use regex for a simple search.
2) Open the file in a `with` statement.
3) Just create a boolean variable to tell you when you see the desired line:

```
with open('buffer.txt', 'r') as f:
    start_printing = False
    for line in f.readlines():
        if start_printing:
            print(line)
        elif 'XXX' in line:
            start_printing = True
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
file = open('buffer.txt', 'r')
found = False
for line in file:
    if not found:
        if re.search('XXX'. line):
              found = True
    else:
        print(line)
```